# Pop pre-pended div items in jQuery (on message receive)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small function the uses a web socket to receive realtime updates. When a new response is received the function prepends a div in the html. I only want the updates to be shown in a window within the page, ie. only ~10 prepended divs should be showing at the most. Ideally I need to pop the oldest div before it overflows out of its parent div.

My question:

1. How do I pop divs before they overflow the parent? Considering I will receive a response nearly every second or so, what is the most efficient way of doing this?

   ```
   #HTML

   <div class="content">
       <p>archienorman-thesis $ realtime_bitcoin</p>
       <div id="messages"></div>
       <!-- window content -->
   </div>



   #JS FUNCTION

   var total = 0;
   var btcs = new WebSocket('wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv');

   btcs.onopen = function () {
       btcs.send(JSON.stringify({"op": "unconfirmed_sub"}));
   };

   btcs.onmessage = function (onmsg) {
       console.log(response);
       var response = JSON.parse(onmsg.data);
       var amount = response.x.out[0].value;
       var calAmount = amount / 100000000;
       var msgs = $('#messages .message');
       var count = msgs.length;

       if (count == 10) {
           msgs.first().remove();
       }
       $('#messages').prepend("<p class='tx'> Amount: " + calAmount + "</p>");
   }
   ```

Comment: Wouldn't the oldest div be the last one? You're prepending to the array, so the newest should be the `first()` (which you're removing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the container div `overflow: hidden`, check if there is overflow using JS `scrollHeight` and `clientHeight`.

**CSS**

```
#messages {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**JS**

Remove your `if` statement and add this after your `prepend()` line:

```
$('#messages').prepend("<p class='tx'> Amount: " + calAmount + "</p>");
$('#messages').css("overflow", "scroll");
if($('#messages')[0].scrollHeight > $('#messages').height())
    msgs.last().remove();
$('#messages').css("overflow", "hidden");
```

The above quickly makes `#messages` have the `overflow: scroll` property in order for the `scrollHeight` property to work. If there is extra scroll, then it deletes the element.

See [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jh8ehmwv/1/).

---

**NOTE**

See my comment to your question. You should be removing `last()`, not `first()`. See the demo as an example -- try changing `last()` to `first()`, and it will not work.

Comment: I just tested with your suggested changes, and unfortunately there is still an overflow. I also tried making the parent div `overflow: hidden`

Comment: Does the `#messages` div have an explicitly set height (either from CSS or JS)? `overflow: hidden` will not work without it. See the demo for an example.

Comment: That was the problem! Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: @user3939059 I'm glad I helped!

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work. This is test code that will basically remove the extra child elements when their combined width exceeds that of the container.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div>1.Test</div>
  <div>2.Test</div>
  <div>3.Test</div>
  <div>4.Test</div>
  <div>5.Test</div>
  <div>6.Test</div>
  <div>7.Test</div>
  <div>8.Test</div>
  <div>9.Test</div>
  <div>10.Test</div>
  <div>11.Test</div>
  <div>12.Test</div>
  <div>13.Test</div>
  <div>14.Test</div>
  <div>15.Test</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width:1000px;
}

.container div {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Javascript

```
function a () {
var containerWidth = $('div.container').width();
var childWidth = $('div.container div').width();
var childCount = $('div.container div').length;  

var removeCount = (childWidth * childCount) - containerWidth;
if(removeCount > 0) {
    removeCount = Math.floor(removeCount/childWidth);
            console.log(removeCount);
    for(i = childCount; i > (childCount-removeCount); i--) {
      $('div.container div:nth-child('+i+')').remove();
    }

  }
}

a();
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L3r2nk6z/5/